# upload image not move in foler

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have trouble with my website

when i upload an image to my website , the image success to database but cannot moved to image folder

```
$config = array(

'allowed_types'=>'jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp',

'upload_path'=>base_url().'webroot/img/barang',

'max_size'=>'5000'
);
```

Comment: Check if u have write permissions to the folder wer ur uploading tat particular image

Comment: i use window 7 , how to change permission ?

Comment: what OS the server running on?

Answer (score 0):

Just after upload, do this:

`print_r($this->upload->data());`

This will show you exactly what data you have after the upload process has completed. If you see nothing wrong in there, it is possibly what @AmitHorakeri said in the comments above: permissions.

Hope this helps.